# Add Fields in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

Can I add multiple fields whenever I press a button (fields such TextBox) in VB.Net?
I tried this code but it didn't help me

```
Dim cLeft As Integer = 1
Public Function AddNewTextBox() As System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
    Dim txt As New System.Windows.Forms.TextBox()
    Me.Controls.Add(txt)
    txt.Top = cLeft * 25
    txt.Left = 150
    txt.Text = "TextBox " & Me.cLeft.ToString
    cLeft = cLeft + 1
    Return txt
End Function
```

Comment: Please read [ask] and take the [tour].  `but it did'nt help me` doesnt give us much to go on

Comment: Do you mean that you want to enter values into text boxes and then create a control with those properties based on those values?

Comment: i want to set for examlpe 3 rows as textbox in procedure then whenever i click button new row generated

Answer (score 1):

That control will not be visible if it's position is under an other control.
I have some suggestions.

1. Use a flow layout panel control. This will automatically position your controls.
   Just add new controls to the flow layout panel control collection.
2. Test the positions and sizes of other controls on your form and identify a location that isn't inhabited by another control. Then add your control to that location.
3. Hide controls until you need them to be visible.
4. Place controls into a panel und use this as o sort of group to hide or show all relevant controls simultaneously.

**but**
Based on one of the followup questions which you answered, it sounds like you might be looking for a spreadsheet control. In this case, why not simply use a datagridview control?

Comment: thanx man i hide the controls, in my case i don't need datagridview